# Sorting a column in a list by considering first three letters of the element in each cell

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I am working on an application in which I have a C# list of a type that I defined myself and it has about 5 columns and several rows of data. In particular I have a column Term of type string which usually contain alpha-numeric items.

Sample data

```
Term       Strike   Strategy    Volume
F15          405     STRDL      100
Z14          375     PUT        1115
A14          400     STRDL      100
Z14 vs F15   475/500    CS      200
A15-Z15      300/375 3WAY (PS)   25
```

I want to sort the above list based on the first three letters of the Term field giving the number highest priority like in the above sample list all items with number 14, 15.. and then by the alphabet

The resultant data should be something like

```
Term       Strike    Strategy   Volume
A14          400      STRDL     100
Z14          375      PUT       1115    
Z14 vs F15   475/500  CS        200
A15-Z15      300/375  3WAY (PS)  25
F15          405      STRDL     100
```

**Is there a good way to solve this?**

Comment: what code do you have to support what you are trying to do.. will this reside in a DataTable or DataSet..etc..?  or do you have this in a List<Object> be more specific in what you have and what your expected results should be.. sounds like a good job for a query / Stored Procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it like this using linq:

```
var res = theList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Term.Substring(1, 2)))
                 .ThenBy(x => x.Term.Substring(0, 1)).ToList();
```

This will return a new sorted list.